# Polarization of insulators

Tags: electrostatics

I have a major misunderstanding of this topic. To my knowledge, electrons can only move around from atom to atom in conductors, creating a flow of charge. But how can insulators polarize? Isn't polarization electrons moving opposite to the electric field? Can conductors also polarize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, conductors can absolutely polarize like you said because charges are free to roam around in the material. By placing a conductor in an electric the charges will rearrange themselves quite dramatically.

An answer to your question about insulators being polarized can be found in David Griffiths E&M textbook. I'll give a quick snippet of the introduction to chapter 4 which deals with electric fields in matter.

Insulators (and dielectrics) are also able to be polarized. The electrons in insulators/dielectrics are bound quite tightly to the nucleus of their atom.  All they can do is move a bit within the atom or molecule. Such microscopic displacements are not as dramatic as the wholesale rearrangement of charge in a conductor, but their **cumulative effects account for the characteristic behavior of dielectric materials**. So think about what happens to electrons and the nucleus in a **neutral** atom when placed into an electric field **E**. The positively charged nucleus is pushed in the direction of the field, while the electrons are pulled in the opposite direction. Eventually, the nucleus and electrons reach an equilibrium separation due to the applied field and their mutual attraction.

From this, you can define what is called the **dipole moment**

$$
\boldsymbol{p} = \alpha \boldsymbol{E}
$$

where $\alpha$ is the atomic polarizability which depends on the individual atoms of a material.